# In TiDB how do you work around the issue where even for indexes, you can't write continuous values to avoid hotspots?

Tags: tidb

In TiDB, due to its range scan-based sharded nature, I understand that you should avoid writing continuous values.
For primary keys, a standard solution is to use auto random rather than auto increment.
Now what should we do if we want to add an index on a time field such as update time or create time?
Certainly, we can't just put a random value here and the continuous nature is inevitable.
What are some design patterns that help to work around this?

Answer (score 2):

With TiDB hotspots can happen. With TiDB the data is stored in TiKV, which is a key-value store. In most cases a [clustered primary key](https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb/stable/clustered-indexes) is used which means that the key in the TiKV layer is basically something like `t_<tableid>_<pk>` with the ID of the table and the primary key of the row.

Rows are stored in [data regions](https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb/stable/tidb-storage#region) which are around 96 MiB in size and store a range of keys.

If you use `AUTO_INCREMENT` then you get values like `1`,`2`,`3`, etc which are going to end up in the same data region. And the primary copy of a data region is on a single server (usually with replicas on two other servers). This means this server has to process the writes for this table and gets more load than other servers. If you use `AUTO_RANDOM` you can avoid this as the random values are likely to be spread over all the data regions for that table. Another option is to use a `NONCLUSTERED` primary key, this means the primary key is basically just a regular index and is not used as key for the TiKV storage. Instead of the PK a generated `_tidb_rowid` will be used instead. There are a few options to influence how the `_tidb_rowid` gets created.

There is a [document describing these solutions](https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb/stable/troubleshoot-hot-spot-issues).

However, if you have a single table without secondary indexes and need good insert performance this might be a problem. However if you have multiple tables and multiple indexes this will probably result in a more even load in total as for one row there might be one region storing the actual row and there might be other regions (on other servers) that store the index.

If you have issues with performance you can look at the [Key Visualizer](https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb/stable/dashboard-key-visualizer), The TiDB Dashoard and Grafana and see if the load is reasonably balanced or not.

In some cases it might make sense to scale out the set of TiKV servers to reduce the total load on a single server and allow the load to be better balanced over all servers.

Note also that hotspots can happen for more than just writes, it can also happen with reads.

Disclaimer: I'm working for PingCAP, the company behind TiDB.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer! I understood your point that if we have many indexes, things will pretty even out. However, how about a case where we have one PK and one index on updated_at? For the PK we can use auto random. But how about for updated_at? Is there any patterns we can use to avoid hotspots?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. If you create a time-column-based secondary index, you will get a hotspot in TiKV. However, there are some that we can consider:

1. The secondary indexes hotspot issue is less severe than the clustered index. That's because the secondary index only records a row ID at the value
   part in TiKV.
2. If we want to release the secondary indexes hotspot issue anyway, we can make a composite index, which means we can build an index on the combination of the time column and a hash column together. For example, if you want to make an index on the `update_at` column, and you have another `uuid` column, you can make an index like this:

   ```sql
   CREATE INDEX combined_index_name ON table_name (update_at, uuid);
   ```

   The core part is that if the `updated_at` is the same, the `uuid` will dominate the order of the key. For example, there are two records:

   | id | updated_at | uuid |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 2023-11-05 17:50:30 | "1_uuid_random" |
   | 2 | 2023-11-05 17:50:30 | "0_uuid_random" |

   In this case, when you build the index of `(update_at, uuid)`, you can revert the order of records. So you can somewhat break hotspots.

In a nutshell, generally speaking, the secondary index won't be your hotspot bottleneck. But when you encounter it as a severe issue, you can use the composite index to work around it.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your confirmation! I see. Secondary indexes are more lightweight than the primary so less of a practical issue. Regarding your suggestion on making a combined index, wouldn't it still be basically increasing though? As the prefix is the updated_at part which is continuous. If uuid part comes first, I understand, but then we can't search by updated_at so it defeats the purpose.

Comment: Oh, the comment can not insert a Markdown table, let me update the answer.

Comment: Hmm, but would the table adapt every second? It seems too short to adapt. Either way, if secondary index is not typically a bottleneck its ok though.